# It's Friday, it's Iceland, and I'm scared

Tags: discussion, fun

From the [Daily Mail](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/article-1266541/Iceland-volcano-England-Wales-airports-closed-7am-Saturday.html):

[image]

Face of the volcano: A radar image shows the crater of Eyjafjallajokull in southeast Iceland which has caused the cloud of volcanic ponies to spread over Europe

Comment: Looks like a mummified lolcat.

Comment: Perhaps a new SO error image?

Comment: Now Iceland is even less ice than before.

Comment: How is Eyjafjallajokull pronounced?

Comment: My best attempt is eye-yaf-yal-lie-yo-kull.

Comment: @gnov I think it's pronounced "I hate you" :)

Comment: @Earlz: Judging by what it's doing to European airlines, perhaps it's pronounced `status-declined`. ;)

Comment: Oh, I thought that was your ultrasound. I was scared too.

Comment: But can you say "Eyjafjallajokull"?

Comment: @Richard http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/Eyjafjallaj%C3%B6kull.ogg

Comment: "How is Eyjafjallajokull pronounced?"  Just like it's spelled.

Answer (score 32):

[Pollyanna's prophecy:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42919/my-calm-rational-assessment-of-the-question-upvote-rep-gain-change-and-ensuing-g)

> ### This site is headed for a disaster of biblical proportions, real wrath of God type stuff.![status](/questions/tagged/status)
>
> *Fire and brimstone coming down from the skies!* [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced)
>
> **Rivers and seas boiling!** [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)
>
> ***Forty years of darkness!*** [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)
>
> *Earthquakes, volcanoes...* [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
>
> ### The dead rising from the grave! Human sacrifice, dogs and cats living together...[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)
>
> *Mass hysteria!* [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Comment: *Rivers and seas boiling!* `[status-deferred]`?

Comment: @json -depends on whether the lava is getting to the water or not.  I'd say `[status-completed]`.

Comment: "dogs and cats living together" `[status-norepro]`

Comment: No waffles?????

Comment: Oh this is nice!  I wondered why that post suddenly got attention today...  I love the tags you've added!  That's awesome.

Comment: What's up with the formatting? I don't get it.

Answer (score 14):

Turns out the [Face on Mars](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Martian_face_viking_cropped.jpg) is actually a virus planets can get. I think Earth and Mars had a thing a while ago and this is the result.

Lately it's been awkward between them... Mars is kinda cold and distant.

Comment: Earth definitely has a much, much worse case.  Perhaps, Mars was right and Earth gave it to him, not the other way around.

Comment: @tvanfosson: it doesn't matter if it was venereal. Is Mars the Sollar System's slut? [Find out](http://www.thesun.co.uk)!

Answer (score 10):

Edvard Munch paints *'the scream'* in **1893** (1 + 8 + 9 + 3 = 21 = 2 + 1 = **3**).

This volcano erupts in **2010** (2 + 0 + 1 + 0 = **3**)

Coincidence? I DON'T THINK SO

Consider this: **2010-1893** = 117 (and 1 + 1 + 7 = 9 = **3** * **3** !!!)

[image: scream][image: ???]]

Comment: I see you are a proponent of the Mayan calendar

Answer (score 10):

This should make you feel better:

[image: Rainbow unicorn]

Comment: + 1 . It does !

Comment: +1 for cheery things!

Answer (score 4):

Don't Mess With The Vikings or they'll smite you!

Answer (score 3):

Uh Oh!

I mean

[image: Uh Oh!]

Answer (score 0):

Ragnarok has begun. Weep and flee.

Comment: The online capabilities of this Ragnarok are quite nice, though.