# How do you use TeX on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, latex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Latex in Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-in-stack-overflow)

I've been trying to figure out how to add TeX equations to my posts on SO. Can anyone tell me how to do that, and give an example?

Comment: I don't think you can do that on SO - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-in-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

It is only implemented on some SE site like http://math.stackexchange.com. However, as a workaround you can use an image rendering like mentioned in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53436/146482).